# How to format a column text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question about SQL Server. In a column of `nvarchar` datatype, the data is formatted like this:

```
Hi XXX,

we do confirm that your assumption is correct.

Here in the following is the list data
deletion:

'1111111111'
,'222222222'
,'333333333'
,'444444444'
```

When I copy this above data from a column and paste in Notepad, it is showing the above format.

When I import this table's data into another table, it is not formatted as shown above. It is showing normal text and no line breaks when I copy and paste in Notepad.

How can I achieve this scenario in SQL Server?

Comment: Your're copying data from SSMS?

Comment: How are you importing this table data into another table? If you are copy and pasting the data to an insert statement it won't keep the line breaks. You need to use CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) to represent a line break if you want to see the result reflected when copying the column data to notepad.

Comment: I think there is no need to have line breaks while copying data from one column into another column in a SQL Server database table

Comment: Now, we would like to know how the data imported from one table to other table ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal for a SQL Server database table not to show line breaks when the data is stored in the tables. Because those line breaks are assumed as a char in that column.

As I understand your problem is not being able to retain line breaks after you copied your data to a new table and copying that in notepad. So here I worked an example. I have copied data with `SELECT`.It worked as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE x1(col NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO x1(col) VALUES('With line breaks
breaks
breaks');

SELECT * FROM x1; -- I copied data to notepad. It worked fine

CREATE TABLE x1_COPY(col NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT into x1_COPY(col) SELECT col from x1;

SELECT * from x1_COPY; -- I copied data to notepad. It worked fine
```

**UPDATE 2** Here I have worked with your data.

```
CREATE TABLE x1(col NVARCHAR(max));

INSERT INTO x1(col) VALUES('Hi XXX,

we do confirm that your assumption is correct.

Here in the following is the list data
deletion:

1111111111
,222222222
,333333333
,444444444');

SELECT * FROM x1

CREATE TABLE x1_COPY(col NVARCHAR(max));

INSERT into x1_COPY(col) SELECT col from x1; -- I have copied that column data with SELECT

SELECT * from x1_COPY -- After copying result of this in notepad. The result was as expected
```